# Graphviz not running in jupyter notebook python = 3.6?

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, graphviz

I am trying to run graphviz to view dot file on jupyter notebook in have imported path to dot.exe path.

G:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflowgpu\Library\bin\graphviz
G:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflowgpu\Library\bin\graphviz\dot.exe

I am trying to run this code:

```
with open("tree1.dot") as f:
dot_graph = f.read()
graphviz.Source(dot_graph)
```

OR

```
graphviz.Source("tree1.dot") .view()
```

It is giving:

```
failed to execute ['dot', '-Tsvg'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH
```

Please tell me any way to fix this or any other way to **View dot file on jupyter notebook i am running python 3.6 on jupter notebook**

Comment: I solved this problem on debian by installing `graphviz` (not just `pip install graphviz`, but the actual executable which is available separately). Not sure how to solve it on Windows though...

Answer (score 13):

I have been having a similar issue (different execution - but both have the same errors in Jupyter) and was able to resolve it this way:

First I uninstalled the graphviz package I had originally installed via the Anaconda prompt.

```
conda remove graphviz
```

I found in [this issue thread](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1666) to use the below command to install the graphviz package. Appending graphviz with python- downloads the package in lib/site-packages

```
conda install python-graphviz
```

I restarted Jupyter Notebook in order to find dot.exe since I couldn't get it to find it in my running notebook after installing the package.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

if you code doesn´t work, you can use this.

```
import graphviz
from IPython.display import display
with open("tree1.dot") as f:
dot_graph = f.read()
display(graphviz.Source(dot_graph))
```

Answer (score 1):

the following worked for me (removal in Jupyter via 'conda remove graphviz' didn't work):

go to Anaconda Navigator Console:

-->Environments--> Search for graphviz --> deinstall

-->Environments --> install python-graphviz

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall graphviz

```
conda remove graphviz 
conda install python-graphviz
graphviz.Source(dot_graph).view()
```

after you will have a small window where you have to choose where you want see your decision tree